# Regex syntax for url redirection

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using this wordpress plugin for redirection which offers regex https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

I've always been completely baffled with regex syntax so I tried this and it doesn't work

```
source:    ^/(.*)/blog/(.*)$
target;    ^/(.*)/(.*)$
```

for redirecting

```
http://example.com/anycategory/blog/anypage
```

to

```
http://example.com/anycategory/anypage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give regex in regex. You need to use back-reference of capturing groups from source and have it like this:

```
source:    ^/?([^/]+)/blog/(.*)$
target;    /$1/$2
```

Comment: what is the purpose of  this here `/?`

Comment: That makes leading slash optional.

Comment: @anubhava how to restrict (.*) to letters only ? thanks.

Comment: You can change `(.*)` to `([a-zA-Z]+)` to restrict to letters only.

Comment: @anubhava tried: ^/?([^/]+)/blog/([a-zA-Z]+)$ weirdly doesn't work anymore

Comment: There might be some non-alphabet characters after `blog/`. I think it is safer to use: `^/?([^/]+)/blog/([\w-]+)/?$`